# Multiple File Upload with CodeIgniter - Offset Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, multiple-file-upload

I simply can't upload multiple files using PHP Codeigniter.
It's uploading the first image I selected,but for the rest, it results
with an offset error.

Can anyone enlighten me,what am I doing wrong?

**View file:**

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url('upload/dosya_yukle'); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="file" name="dosya[]" multiple>
    <br><br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Yükle</button>
</form>
```

**Controller method:**

```
    public function dosya_yukle () {

        $count = count($_FILES['dosya']['name']);

        for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) { 

            $_FILES['dosya']['name'] = $_FILES['dosya']['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['dosya']['type'] = $_FILES['dosya']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['dosya']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['dosya']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['dosya']['error'] = $_FILES['dosya']['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['dosya']['size'] = $_FILES['dosya']['size'][$i];

            $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img';
            $config['allowed_types'] =  'gif|jpg|png';

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            $this->upload->do_upload('dosya');

        }
    }
```

**Error I get :**

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Uninitialized string offset: 2
>
> Filename: controllers/Upload.php
>
> Line Number: 54
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\wamp64\www\ajquery\application\controllers\Upload.php Line:
>   54 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\wamp64\www\ajquery\index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update controller as follows..

```
public function dosya_yukle () {

        $count = count($_FILES['dosya']['name']);
        $files = $_FILES;
        unset($_FILES);
        for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) { 

            $_FILES['dosya']['name'] = $files['dosya']['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['dosya']['type'] = $files['dosya']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['dosya']['tmp_name'] = $files['dosya']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['dosya']['error'] = $files['dosya']['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['dosya']['size'] = $files['dosya']['size'][$i];

            $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img';
            $config['allowed_types'] =  'gif|jpg|png';

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            $this->upload->do_upload('dosya');

        }
    }
```